# Ajax request handled by php returns NULL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to send data from the browser's local storage to php using AJAX, when I test the API using postman by inserting this data(POST)
**[
{
"product-id": "32",
"product-name": "Reese Stevenson",
"product-description": "Ea tempore temporib",
"product-image": "Screenshot_3.png",
"product-price": "778 "
}
]**

which is the same data in local storage I get back this object as a response(POST & GET METHODS) which is the thing I want for the moment (starting small before scaling the API and integrating it with the whole application )

so when I tried to make the request using AJAX:

```
const storedProduct = localStorage.getItem("product-id");
const products = JSON.parse(storedProduct);

(function products_to_backend() {

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "localhost:9000/frontEndProductsHandler.php",true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type" , "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    
    xhr.addEventListener("load",function(){
        
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
            console.log(`server status : 200 OK : ${xhr.responseText}`);
        }else if(xhr.status === 404){
            console.log("NOT FOUND");
        }
    });
    
    xhr.addEventListener("error", function(){
        console.log(`request faild : ${xhr.statusText}`);
    });
        
    console.log(typeof(JSON.parse(storedProduct)))
    xhr.send(JSON.parse(storedProduct));

})();
```

the PHP script :

```
<?php 

    

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'] === "application/json"){
        
        $requestBody = file_get_contents("php://input");

        $data = json_decode($requestBody);
        
        if($data){
            http_response_code(201);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }else{
            http_response_code(400);
        }
        
    }else{
        http_response_code(404);
        die();
    };
```

Thanks in advance, and I hope that I described the issue well.

Comment: php://input may be false at file_get_contents().

Comment: Also the HTTP code is 201 in your PHP script and the JS checks for 200.

Comment: I was trying to check if the server responds correctly and I forgot it there. and for php://input is the way I retrieve data from the request. I'll google it to find out another method

Comment: `xhr.oen` is misspelled. Also the http:// or https:// protocol is missing.

Comment: Thanks , I totally forgot about the protocol. and for the xhr.open I edited the question because it was spelled right in the source code i might just touch it by mistake. but what solved my problem is that relazing that there was no need encode the data to a json since it's already a json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first problem was that i forgot about HTTP protocol in the end point , thanks to Markus Zeller to notice it.

And the second this was that i'm actually encoding the data into json even tho its already a json.

So that the new version of the script :
js :

```
(function products_to_backend() {

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:9000/controller/handlers/frontEndProductsHandler.php",true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type" , "application/json");
    
    xhr.addEventListener("load",function(){
        
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
            console.log(`server status : 200 OK : ${xhr.responseText}`);
        }else if(xhr.status === 404){
            console.log("NOT FOUND");
        }
    });
    
    xhr.addEventListener("error", function(){
        console.log(`request faild : ${xhr.statusText}`);
    });
        
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(storedProduct));

})();
```

php :

```
<?php 

    

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'] === "application/json"){
        
        $requestBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
        

        $data = $requestBody;
        
        if($data){
            http_response_code(200);
            echo json_decode($data);
        }else{
            http_response_code(400);
        }
        
    }else{
        http_response_code(404);
        die();
    };
```